# parabola in homogeneous coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, matrices, coordinate-systems, parametric

So if I have the parabola $Y = X^2$, how do I go about representing this homogeneously?  I know I can parameterize it as $F(t) = (t, t^2)$, but then what?

The reason I ask is because I have a $3\times 3$ matrix that I want to apply to this parabola but before I can do that I need to get it in the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reformulate this to $x^2 - y = 0$
2. Homogenize to $x^2 - yz = 0$
3. Write quadratic form as a matrix:
   $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
   A point $p$ lies on this parabola if it satisfies $p^T\cdot A\cdot p=0$.
4. Symmetrize this matrix:
   $$B = A+A^T = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
5. If you want to apply a projective transformation $M$ to all points, i.e. $p\mapsto M\cdot p$, then you can transform the matrix of your conic section to $(M^{-1})^T\cdot B\cdot M^{-1}$.